# CiviCRM CRM_Core_DAO::VALUE_SEPARATOR how to use it in pure SQL

Tags: mysql, checkbox, phpmyadmin, separator, civicrm

I am having to populate custom fields through phpMyAdmin (when using CiviCRM), I have created the SQL statements required ... e.g.

```
UPDATE 'table' SET 'field1'='11213'
```

... but, one of the fields is used to store multiple checkbox selections (so for the example stated previously: if field1 was being used to store checkbox selections it could be that 1, 12, 13 are the checkboxes selections).

... Now my initial investigation highlights that CiviCRM uses Ctrl+A character to separate checkbox selections, and if I was coding an update I could just use CRM_Core_DAO::VALUE_SEPARATOR to insert the separator character into the query.

But, how do I add the separator character if I'm updating values through phpMyAdmin (e.g. SQL statements) and not through php code?

Comment: MySQL's CONCAT_WS (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) might help you out.

Comment: Thanks @Raymond Nijland that's a pretty interesting piece of info.. sure it will come in handy at some point... At this current stage it looks like I need to find a way to convert "\u0001" which is the ascii value for Ctrl+A so that mysql reads it as a deliminator - using concat_ws ("\u0001",item1,item2) doesn't see to work... does mySQL have a function to turn "\u001" into a char equivalent?

Comment: \u0001 is unicode...  i believe \u0001 can be rewritten as X'01'

Comment: Any thoughts on how you'd use that with concat_ws?  E.g. UPDATE table SET field=concat_ws ('x01',value1,value2);  without MySQL actually storing the string x01value1x01value2?

Comment: You are using 'X01' instead of X'01'.. X'01' stands for hexadecimal string...`UPDATE table SET field=concat_ws (X'01',value1,value2)`  should store the string as `value1[SOH]value2`

Comment: Many thanks Raymond Nijland for your help on this... it worked a treat

Answer (score 0):

Credit to those whom helped with this (see above comments) and especially Raymond Nijland .

The use of X'01 had the effect of adding the "Start of Heading" character to the SQL query, which is what was required.  E.g.

```
UPDATE table SET field=concat_ws (X'01,value1,value2)
```

Comment: I think that would have been (X'01',value1,value2) not (X'01,value1,value2) - and had my fingers crossed but for SET extends_entity_column_value=concat_ws (X'01',Student,Alumni,Prospective_Student,Past_Student) i got: Unknown column 'Student' in 'field list'